# Can't install Golang on Solaris via pkg - release/evaluation dependency

Tags: solaris, pkg

On a new installation of Solaris 11.3 on Sparc hardware, I'm trying to install Golang but am getting the following problem:

```
# pkg install --accept developer/golang
Creating Plan (Solver setup): |
pkg install: No matching version of developer/golang can be installed:
  Reject:  pkg://solaris/developer/golang@1.7-5.12.0.0.0.122.0
  Reason:  No version for 'require' dependency on release/evaluation can be found
```

I'm new to Solaris but have installed a few other things via pkg and am also familiar with other packaging systems on Linux systems (rpm, apt, etc).

What am I missing?

The missing dependency on release/evaluation doesn't seem to be something I can install, and I've seen a post about 11.4 and FOSS software installs not having nasty "surprises" like 11.3 (which I think I've just found), but I can't see what those surprises are.

NB: if it's relevant, I'm not currently using zones/etc, I'm just treating the system as one machine.

Comment: This looks like it might be relevant:  https://superuser.com/questions/1092912/no-version-for-optional-dependency-when-updating-solaris-11-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The release/evaluation package has been removed from the repository to prevent any further installations of the fairly dated evaluation packages as these present issues in updates going forward.  If you're interested in trying golang, we'd recommend installing the 11.4 beta release that's now available, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/114beta/solaris114beta-4257760.html

Comment: Thanks - I think that answers the question.  Sadly, 11.4 is out of the question for me - my hardware is fairly old (T3) and not supported by 11.4 anymore (11.3 is the last release to support my CPU).

Answer (score 0):

### Get package dependencies

```
$ pkg contents -r -o fmri,type -t depend developer/golang-15

FMRI                                         TYPE
pkg:/runtime/perl-522@5.22.1-5.12.0.0.0.95.0 require
pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.3.0   require
release/evaluation                           require
```

### To display perl version

```
$ perl --version

This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 5 (v5.12.5) built for i86pc-solaris-thread-multi-64
```

### Package is available for x86 only and requires perl 5.22

### Unlock perl-512 and allow it to be upgraded

```
$ pgk change-facet facet-version-lock.runtime/perl-512=false

$ pkg install golang-15
```

or

```
$ pkg install --accept developer/golang
```